# Error using link_to with to_sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some problems using link_to with to_sentence in Rails.

Using this line of code the html output is wrong.

```
<%= @story.collections.map{ |u| link_to(u.name, collection_path(u)).html_safe }.to_sentence %>
```

This code is rendered as text on the page rather than the links

```
<a href="/collections/One">One</a>, <a href="/collections/Two">Two</a>, and <a href="/collections/Three">Three</a>
```

This is what I want instead

[One](/collections/One), [Two](/collections/Two), and [Three](/collections/Three)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Move the .html_safe after the to_sentence

Answer (score 0):

Use [safe join](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-safe_join) as a helper method like this:

In helper:

```
def story_links(story)
  links = @story.collections.map{ |u| link_to(u.name, collection_path(u)).html_safe }
  safe_join(links, ',')
end
```

In the view:

```
<%= story_links(@story) %>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this but I need the "and" part. This gives me "One, Two, Three". I need "One, Two and Three".

Comment: Maybe instead of `safe_join(links, ',')` just do `links.to_sentence` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= @story.collections.map{ |u| link_to(u.name, collection_path(u))}.to_sentence.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?